# How do I find the source code repository of an apt package

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a package that I installed through apt. It's from the default repository, so in theory it should be open source, somewhere. The question is, how do I find that out now. The package in question is `network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome`. I am looking into porting it to a different distribution. For that I need the source code.

```bash
$ apt policy network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome
network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome:
  Installed: 1.2.10-0ubuntu3
  Candidate: 1.2.10-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.10-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: If you go to the packages website ther is also the source code available. https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome Look for `Download Source Package` on these pages.

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-get-source-code-of-package-using-the-apt-command-on-debian-or-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the sources package in your `sources.list`.

The package come from Universe repository. In your case, it is enabled, so you need to enable Universe sources:

command line:

```
echo "deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe" |
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/universe.list
```

Or you can write changes to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` manually.

Update your packages list:

```
sudo apt update
```

Download the source:

```
apt source network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this. If there is an easier way then please do tell, but for now what I did was call `apt policy network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome` and then go to the package source. In this case `http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` where in turn I looked for my Ubuntu version, so the final path looks like this `/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/source`. I then downloaded the `Sources.xz` file and grep-ed through it to find the source repository of the package where the code is stored. In this case `https://salsa.debian.org/lkundrak-guest/network-manager-fortisslvpn`